# counters updated according to two different conditions within a loop

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to make a call billing program in c++. One of the features of this small program is the ability to update discount minutes spoken within discount hours and normal-priced minutes during business hours, depending on which time stretch is entered.

The user first enters the time as a string like this 22:00

Then I have a function which takes the string and turns it into an integer. For example the 22:00 above is turned into 2200

I have then another help function that takes an int, the int above and turns it to the decimal time.

```
double turnTimeToDecimal(int timeRaw){

    double decimalTime;

    decimalTime = timeRaw * 0.01;

        return decimalTime;
 }
```

The business hours which bear no discount and are between 8.00 am and 18.30am in order to deal with this feature I update two counters inside a for loop that goes from 0 to 1417minutes (24hrs):

```
double myStartDecimal = 0.0;
double myStopDecimal = 0.0;

myStartDecimal = turnTimeToDecimal(myStartRaw);
myStopDecimal = turnTimeToDecimal(myStopRaw);


//hours and minutes start
int  hourStart = (int)floor(myStartDecimal);
int minuteStart = (int)round(100*(myStartDecimal - hourStart));

//hours and minutes stop
int hourStop = (int)floor(myStopDecimal);
int minuteStop = (int) round(100*(myStopDecimal - hourStop));

int totalMinutesPremium = 0;
int totalMinutesDiscount = 0;
int i = 0;

int k = 0;
for(k = (hourStart* 60) + minuteStart; k < (hourStop * 60) + minuteStop + round(((double)minuteStop/100)); k++){


    //will update the corresponding counter depending 
    //on the time stretch, business hours 8.00 - 18.30.
    if(hourStart >= 8 && hourStop < 18.5){
        totalMinutesPremium++;
    }else{
        totalMinutesDiscount++;
    }
}

//will give total minutes
cout << " k is: " << k << endl;

//will give the total number of minutes during the business hours and 
//the total number of minutes during the discount hours(non-bussiness hours)
cout << "Total minutes premium " << round(totalMinutesPremium) << 
        " Total Minutes discount " << round(totalMinutesDiscount) << endl;
```

However, the program does detects whether the time stretch entered is within business hours or not, except in one case. If the time for example lies between 7:30 and 8:30 (business hours between 7:59-18:30) it does not return the combination of minutes within the business hours which I would expect to be 30 min and minutes within the discount hours which I would expect to be 30 minutes as well, since the discount stretch ends at 07:59 and it starts again at 18:31.

Hopefully I made myself clear.

Comment: where is the declaration of `hourStop`? (and more specifically, what is its type?)

Comment: Is hourStart a floating point variable? I'm guessing it is int? I would suggest doing the math on the hours and using a difference in time rather than a loop... that's a very expensive way to go about it

Comment: You're not using `k` inside the loop, so you either only add to `totalMinutesDiscount` or to `totalMinutesPremium`, which is probably not what you want. You should try to get rid of the loop entirely, as you can find the time difference with simple subtraction.

Comment: sorry I omitted that info, I have updated the code above and included that information. However HourStop is an int. same thing goes for hourStart

Comment: You convert "22:30" into 2200? Then you convert that into `22.00`? And you think there are 1417 minutes in 24 hours? *Just do everything in integer minutes, and have someone else check your work!*

Comment: @Beta I don't convert 22:30 into 2200 it is a typo which I have updated now. What I want is to get the 22:00 in decimal so I do 2200*0.01 I deal with all the values in minutes and it is 1440

Comment: @riv that is exactly what happened thank you! I have added this interval inside the for loop and now it works (k >= 480  && k < 1110 ) I think that K Scott's solution is better because the loop is not needed though. Thnx again for the help you all!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `for` loop, you allocate the given minute depending on `hourStart` and `hourStop`, *not* on whether the given minute is during business hours. If the call encroaches on discount hours, then the whole call will be discounted.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a loop? Why not just do the math?

While not the complete code answer... you can fill in the blanks...

```
if( startTime >= startOfPremiumPeriod && endTime <= endOfPremiumPeriod )
   totalMinutesPremimum = endTime - startTime;
else if( startTime < startOfPremiumPeriod && endTime < startOfPremimumPeriod )
   totalMinutesDiscount = endTime - startTime;
.... etc. etc. etc.
```

You can take into account the case where the start time is before midnight and the end time after midnight by adding 24 hours to the end time...

```
if( endTime < startTime ) endTime += 1440;
```

Comment: @K Scott I thought that as the hour cannot go beyond 24 it should only run until 23:59

Comment: If (endTime < startTime ) endTime += 24 hours;

Answer (score 0):

> "However HourStop is an int. same thing goes for hourStart"

Then it's not going to work, if can't use decimal values with `int`s like you do here:

```
hourStop < 18.5
```

well.. you *can* but it's not going to work the way you want it to. If you have `int hourStop = 18.5` then it's going to get truncated to 18 since it can't be a fractional number. You need to use a different type, such as `double`

Also, the condition in your loop depends on `hourStart` and `hourStop` which are never changing in the loop:

```
if(hourStart >= 8 && hourStop < 18.5){
```

So you'll always hit the same `if` condition (which ever it is)

Comment: what if I cast it to a double?

Comment: @user1179105 - no, that doesn't work, it only allows you to *assign* double values to it without warnings. The type is still an `int` and it will still truncate everything after the decimal point.